# Where does VSCode store files related to markdown codeblock syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm trying to find the files necessary to add my own syntax highlighting to fenced code blocks in a markdown document within Visual Studio Code. e.g.

````
```Python
# Comment
print("hello world")
```
````

will provide syntax highlighting for Python. I'm trying to add syntax highlighting for an unsupported language.

I have tried to find these on my own, but it's been all guesswork. I've found what looks like related files under C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions. There's a markdown-basics folder within there that contains a syntaxes\markdown.tmLanguage.json that appears to contain fenced code block references, but not the actual syntax definitions. There's also folders for a variety of languages. Trying to create a new definition based on these doesn't seem to work though.

I would appreciate any help figuring out how fenced code block syntax is defined.

Comment: you can inject a block for different language in a TextMate grammar file, VSC uses the TextMate grammar file for that language

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're saying is that I can use a grammar file to create my own syntax highlighting. That does help a bit, but doesn't really address how I apply it. I.e. where do I save this file? Also, keep in mind that I'm looking for markdown highlighting. This appears to be controlled differently then file language mode. E.g. I can install a plugin to get highlighting of a given language, but that doesn't mean it's supported within markdown.

Comment: you have to modify the markdown TM grammar file to inject your custom language, or create a feature request that allows extensions to inject language blocks in existing TM grammars, to get syntax highlighting for your custom language create an extension

Comment: And again, where is this file?

Comment: in the extension that supplies this TM grammar file, as a contribution point in the package.json file